# Troubleshooting XDCAM import into Premirere Pro CC 2014

Tags: premiere, windows, transcoding, prores

I am in the middle of editing a TV spot we create bi-weekly and therefore on a tight timeline. I am using Premiere Pro CC (2014) just upadted last week on Win8.1, 4790k, 16GB, OS SSD 256GB, Project Drive 1TB SSD, Export and Preview Drive 3TB Seagate 7200. They shot this particular spot in a studio with different cameras.  So I recieved files in: XDCAM HD 1080 422 i60 50mb CBR 1920x1080 - 1888x1062

My understanding is that XDCAM is supported natively in PPro, however, when I try to import into Premiere or add to Media Encoder I recieve error: "Codec missing or unavailable".

I asked a friend to re-encode it as ProRes rather than spend time figuring out -what I assumed was a codec issue. But the ProRes 422 LT that he exported
I get error: "The importer reported a generic error". I'll say that I've been using prores on this same system a bunch of times, however it was a different possibly less savey person who did this transcode and so it is possibly still suspect.

These files were live edited on some box so the file is over an hour long.. could it be a RAM issue? I've jogged my page file up to a static 120GB..

I am able to play the prores files on a second laptop that has no adobe suite installed.. but still cannot export them from quicktime as something else. I get an error.

Comment: Since CS5 xdcam files are supported natively. Did you've tried to open it via sony clip browser?

Comment: its a good thought, just tried it and no XDCAM EX Clip Browser does not "see" the files. They are in an MOV wrapper.  Is XDCAM HD format MXF always it looked like maybe it got an MOV wrapper in some cameras?

Comment: Never seen this. Are you sure that the files are the original ones?

Comment: no.. unfortunately not. There are 2 or 3 people between me and the shooters. This particular one was live edited.. so l it may well have been saved from the box. I was told they were sending me XDCAM HD.. so I thought no problem.

Comment: You could try to open it in after effects, it's more robust in such cases...

Comment: I actually did try that. I ended up downloading a demo of Calibrated.. and installed. No I can play the "XDCAM" files in QT (watermark) the suprise was not the "ProRes" files load into PPro.. and are useable (no watermark). I am currently attempting to transcode the "ProRes" to DNxHD.. which I plan to then edit with. 
http://www.calibratedsoftware.com/Products/XDDecodeV2/QXDDownload.php

Comment: sounds horrible ;)

Comment: Yes, absolutely.. I have no idea. But the demo codec seemed to work and get me to DNx, which are working fine.  Thanks for the suggestions @poor

Comment: Glad I could help :) Written an answer for general troubleshooting, just to have one, because our answer ratio needs work, see: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4/audio-video-production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since Adobe CS5 XDCAM files are supported natively**, make sure the folder structure is the same like on your SXS Card, open up the [**Sony Clip Browser**](https://pro.sony.com/bbsc/ssr/micro-xdcam/resource.downloads.bbsccms-assets-micro-xdcam-downloads-XDZP1TC.shtml) and try to load up the files - this should work immediately. If you can't see the files, there must be an encoding error or the files are corrupt.